# Scala can't recognize which method to call

Tags: scala

I want to run a bit of Java in Scala console. Here's what I get:

```
scala> String.format("hello %d",3);
<console>:8: error: overloaded method value format with alternatives:
  (java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String <and>
  (java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String
 cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, Int)
              String.format("hello %d",3);
```

Why Scala can't recognize which method to call, if argument set is different, and the ones I provide are quite unambigous?

What is strange, the same message appears also when I try to call function with arguments which don't match to any of both argument sets, e.g. `String.format()`

I was using scala 2.9.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your arguments don't match the function prototype. You're calling the function with second argument [`scala.Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) which is not a `java.lang.Object`.

Convert it to `java.lang.Integer` and it will work.

See also [boxing and unboxing in Scala](http://www.ansorg-it.com/en/scalanews-001.html).

Comment: that link is throwing a 404

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to use the new String interpolators available in Scala 2.10.X.
They are easier to use.

```
  val x = 3
  String.format("hello %d", x: Integer)
```

would be simply:

```
  val x =3 
  s"hello $x"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
String.format("hello %d",3.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Object]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can let Scala do the boxing for you:

```
String.format("hello %d", 3: Integer)
```